# What is an associative container? Have to change QList given to this container

Tags: c++, qt

I have an assignment and I don't really understand what to do. I must rewrite an application (which was in a previous assignment and we got the answers) so that m_TransactionList of SavingsAccount is an appropriate associative container instead of a QList. I will give the parts of code where the m_TransactionList were used. It's alot of code if I post everything.. We have the following .h and .cpp files: deposit, withdrawal, balanceenquiry, transaction and savingsaccount.

Here is savingsaccount.h

```
#ifndef SAVINGSACCOUNT_H
#define SAVINGSACCOUNT_H

#include "transaction.h"

class SavingsAccount{
public:
    SavingsAccount(QString name, QString num);
    ~SavingsAccount();
    void addTransaction(Transaction* t);
    double totalTransactionCost()const;
    QString frequentTransactionType() const;
    QList<Transaction*> transactionsOnADate(QDate date) const;
    QString toString() const;

private:
    QString m_CustomerName;
    QString m_AccountNumber;
    QList<Transaction*> m_TransactionList;
};

#endif // SAVINGSACCOUNT_H
```

savingsaccount.cpp

```
#include <QStringList>
#include "savingsaccount.h"

SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(QString name, QString num): m_CustomerName(name), m_AccountNumber(num){
}

SavingsAccount::~SavingsAccount(){
    qDeleteAll(m_TransactionList);
}

void SavingsAccount::addTransaction(Transaction *t){
    m_TransactionList.append(t);
 }

double SavingsAccount::totalTransactionCost()const{
    double cost = 0.0;
    foreach(Transaction* t, m_TransactionList){
        cost +=t->computeCost();
    }
    return cost;
}

QString SavingsAccount::frequentTransactionType() const{

    int dCount = 0, wCount = 0, beCount =0, mostCount = 0;
    QString dTransaction = "Deposit", wTransaction = "Withdrawal", beTransaction = "Balance Enquiry";
    QStringList result;

    foreach(Transaction* t, m_TransactionList){
        QString type = t->getType();       
        if (type == dTransaction)
            dCount++;
        if (type ==  wTransaction)
            wCount++;
        if (type == beTransaction)
            beCount++;
    }

    mostCount = dCount > wCount ? dCount : wCount;
    mostCount = beCount > mostCount ? beCount : mostCount;

    if (mostCount == dCount)
        result.append(dTransaction);
    if (mostCount == wCount)
        result.append(wTransaction);
    if (mostCount == beCount)
        result.append(beTransaction);

    return result.join(", ");

}

QList<Transaction *> SavingsAccount::transactionsOnADate(QDate date) const{
  QList<Transaction*> result;
  foreach(Transaction* t, m_TransactionList){
      if (t->getDateTime().date() == date)
          result.append(t);
  }
  return result;
}

QString SavingsAccount::toString() const{
    QString result = QString("Customer name: %1, Account number: %2\n").arg(m_CustomerName).arg(m_AccountNumber);
    foreach(Transaction* t, m_TransactionList){
        result.append(t->toString());
        result.append("\n");
    }

    return result;
}
```

I'm not sure what to do and what to change!

Comment: An "associative container" is also often called a "map", as it "maps" a key to a value. See e.g. [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) for an example of a associative container. The Qt framework do of course have a similar container as well. Next time you have a phrase you don't understand, I suggest you go to your favorite search engine and look for it, as then you would have found the answer pretty quick yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Qt has a number of associative containers:

```
QMap      - a generic map/dictionary, implemented as a R/B tree since Qt5
QMultimap - same as QMap, but has API for multiple values per key
QHash     - a generic hashmap, can be significantly faster than QMap as element count increases
QMutihash - like QHash, but has API for multiple values per key
```

In order for your type to work with those, `QMap` and `QMultimap` requires the `<` operator, while `QHash` and `QMultihash` require the `==` operator and a free `uint qHash(T)` function.

Those requirements to not apply if you use pointers, since they already have those requirements implemented.

However, in order to use an associative container, you need to have a key for every value, and in regard to transactions, that would probably be an integer ID. Which brings me to the point - if transaction IDs are per savings account they would be sequential, in other words you will be better off with the `QList` or even better, a `QVector` because it will be a little more efficient, since you will only be appending transactions.

Also, some may argue that `QList` and `QVector` can also be regarded as associative containers, because the index can effectively be seen as a key. The main difference is how elements are stored, whether they are sequential in memory or not, and whether they are ordered or unordered, each one having its own advantages and drawbacks, and satisfies a particular usage requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay in the Qt-world you can change `QList<T>` to `QMap<K,T>`, where K will be your key and T your value. This will also require you to define the type of the key (probably `QString` or `int`) and changing iterations to using a `QMapIterator<K,T>`. This is actually a pretty easy job, but its very good for understanding the difference in containers.

```
//Define
QMap<QString,Transaction> transactionList;
//Insert
transactionList.insert("first", new Transaction(...)); // Transaction 1
transactionList.insert("second", new Transaction(...)); // Transaction 2
//Use
Transaction* t = transactionList.value("first"); // Will return Transaction 1
```